# Imposm full database schema import template

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, imposm

I noticed that the default imposm template for importing OSM data into postgis lacks some types of features (powerlines for example). I was searching the web to find a complete schema import template (in the form of python classes, like the default template) but couldn't find any, does it exist? It would be much easier to have a complete template, then remove what you dont need.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment and it seems, that imposm isn't able to import routes until now.

Comment: It can, but you need to add some python classes yourself (in my case for powerlines)

Comment: Can you give an example for that?